# How to transform an IplImage into a char array

Tags: c, arrays, opencv, char, iplimage

I wanted to know if it's possible, and if so, how to transform an IplImage to a char array in C (or C++).
thks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a declaration:

```
IplImage *img = /* ... */
```

`img->imageData` will contain your aligned pixel data (in BGR order)

Comment: that means i can basically do `char bla[sizeof(img)] = img->imageData;` ?

Comment: If you wanted to copy the contents, that would be: `char* bla; blah = malloc(img->width * img->height * img->nChannels * sizeof(char)); memcpy(blah, img->imageData, img->width * img->height * img->nChannels * sizeof(char));`  or something very close to this.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that since `sizeof(img)` will be your architecture's pointer width, which isn't what you want. You probably want this: `char *blah = malloc(img->imageSize); memcpy(blah, img->imageData, img->imageSize);`

Comment: hum... ok i'll try this latter then. i'll post back when i have results. thks for the help:)

Comment: @karlphillip: width*height*channels isn't usually the size of an image. You need to use widthStep. Or better, imageSize.

Comment: @Utkarsh Great, there you go @StinkyCat! As I said, `or something very close to this`

Comment: well.. using @yan's code i get the following error: `char *blah = malloc(img->imageSize);` **error:invalid conversion from ´void*´to ´char*´**.

Comment: btw i think my Code::Blocks doesn't accept/recognize img->imageSize -_- any ideas why? **edit:** my img is ofimage, not iplimage. gonna work on it.

Comment: nope! fixed it and with img being IplImage still gives me that same error :s

Comment: fixed it with `char *blah = (char *)malloc(img->imageSize);`. But if i printf it it doesn't print anything..

Comment: i simply did: `char bla*; blah = img->imageData; int blahIndex = img->imageSize;`. Not sure if it works, but it compiles..

Comment: **correction:** `char *blah;` obviously -_- anyways, i would like to printf it, but it just does nothing..